# Import CSV into Vertica using Rfc4180CsvParser and exclude header row

Tags: c++, csv, sdk, vertica

Is there a way to exclude the header row when importing data via the Rfc4180CsvParser? The `COPY` command has a `SKIP` option but the option doesn't seem to work when using the CSV parsers provided in the Vertica SDK.

**Background**

As background, the [`COPY`](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Statements/COPY/COPY.htm) command does not read CSV files by itself.  For simple CSV files, one can say  `COPY schema.table FROM '/data/myfile.csv' DELIMITER ',' ENCLOSED BY '"';` but this will fail with data files which have string values with embedded quotes.

Adding `ESCAPE AS '"'` will generate an error `ERROR 3169:  ENCLOSED BY and ESCAPE AS can not be the same value` .   This is a problem as CSV values are enclosed and escaped by `"`.

**Vertica SDK CsvParser extensions to the rescue**

Vertica provides an SDK under `/opt/vertica/sdk/examples` with C++ programs that can be compiled into extensions. One of these is `/opt/vertica/sdk/examples/ParserFunctions/Rfc4180CsvParser.cpp`.

This works great as follows:

```
 cd /opt/vertica/sdk/examples
 make clean
 vsql 
 ==> CREATE LIBRARY Rfc4180CsvParserLib AS '/opt/vertica/sdk/examples/build/Rfc4180CsvParser.so';
 ==> COPY myschema.mytable FROM '/data/myfile.csv' WITH PARSER Rfc4180CsvParser();
```

***Problem***

The above works great *except* that it imports the first row of the data file as a row.  The `COPY` command has a `SKIP 1` option but this does not work with the parser.

***Question***

Is it possble to edit `Rfc4180CsvParser.cpp` to skip the first row, or better yet, take some parameter to specify number of rows to skip?

The program is just 135 lines but I don't see where/how to make this incision.  Hints?

Copying the entire program below as I don't see a public repo to link to...

***Rfc4180CsvParser.cpp***

```
/* Copyright (c) 2005 - 2012 Vertica, an HP company -*- C++ -*- */

#include "Vertica.h"
#include "StringParsers.h"
#include "csv.h"

using namespace Vertica;

// Note, the class template is mostly for demonstration purposes,
// so that the same class can use each of two string-parsers.
// Custom parsers can also just pick a string-parser to use.

/**
 * A parser that parses something approximating the "official" CSV format
 * as defined in IETF RFC-4180:  <http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180>
 * Oddly enough, many "CSV" files don't actually conform to this standard
 * for one reason or another.  But for sources that do, this parser should
 * be able to handle the data.
 * Note that the CSV format does not specify how to handle different
 * data types; it is entirely a string-based format.
 * So we just use standard parsers based on the corresponding column type.
 */
template <class StringParsersImpl>
class LibCSVParser : public UDParser {
public:
    LibCSVParser() : colNum(0) {}

    // Keep a copy of the information about each column.
    // Note that Vertica doesn't let us safely keep a reference to
    // the internal copy of this data structure that it shows us.
    // But keeping a copy is fine.
    SizedColumnTypes colInfo;

    // An instance of the class containing the methods that we're
    // using to parse strings to the various relevant data types
    StringParsersImpl sp;

    /// Current column index
    size_t colNum;

    /// Parsing state for libcsv
    struct csv_parser parser;

    // Format strings
    std::vector<std::string> formatStrings;

    /**
     * Given a field in string form (a pointer to the first character and
     * a length), submit that field to Vertica.
     * `colNum` is the column number from the input file; how many fields
     * it is into the current record.
     */
    bool handleField(size_t colNum, char* start, size_t len) {
        if (colNum >= colInfo.getColumnCount()) {
            // Ignore column overflow
            return false;
        }
        // Empty colums are null.
        if (len==0) {
            writer->setNull(colNum);
            return true;
        } else {
            return parseStringToType(start, len, colNum, colInfo.getColumnType(c
olNum), writer, sp);
        }
    }

    static void handle_record(void *data, size_t len, void *p) {
        static_cast<LibCSVParser*>(p)->handleField(static_cast<LibCSVParser*>(p)
->colNum++, (char*)data, len);
    }

    static void handle_end_of_row(int c, void *p) {
        // Ignore 'c' (the terminating character); trust that it's correct
        static_cast<LibCSVParser*>(p)->colNum = 0;
        static_cast<LibCSVParser*>(p)->writer->next();
    }

    virtual StreamState process(ServerInterface &srvInterface, DataBuffer &input
, InputState input_state) {
        size_t processed;
        while ((processed = csv_parse(&parser, input.buf + input.offset, input.s
ize - input.offset,
                handle_record, handle_end_of_row, this)) > 0) {
            input.offset += processed;
        }

        if (input_state == END_OF_FILE && input.size == input.offset) {
            csv_fini(&parser, handle_record, handle_end_of_row, this);
            return DONE;
        }

        return INPUT_NEEDED;
    }

    virtual void setup(ServerInterface &srvInterface, SizedColumnTypes &returnTy
pe);
    virtual void destroy(ServerInterface &srvInterface, SizedColumnTypes &return
Type) {
        csv_free(&parser);
    }
};

template <class StringParsersImpl>
void LibCSVParser<StringParsersImpl>::setup(ServerInterface &srvInterface, Sized
ColumnTypes &returnType) {
    csv_init(&parser, CSV_APPEND_NULL);
    colInfo = returnType;
}

template <>
void LibCSVParser<FormattedStringParsers>::setup(ServerInterface &srvInterface, 
SizedColumnTypes &returnType) {
    csv_init(&parser, CSV_APPEND_NULL);
    colInfo = returnType;
    if (formatStrings.size() != returnType.getColumnCount()) {
        formatStrings.resize(returnType.getColumnCount(), "");
    }
    sp.setFormats(formatStrings);
}

template <class StringParsersImpl>
class LibCSVParserFactoryTmpl : public ParserFactory {
public:
    virtual void plan(ServerInterface &srvInterface,
            PerColumnParamReader &perColumnParamReader,
            PlanContext &planCtxt) {}

    virtual UDParser* prepare(ServerInterface &srvInterface,
            PerColumnParamReader &perColumnParamReader,
            PlanContext &planCtxt,
            const SizedColumnTypes &returnType)
    {
        return vt_createFuncObj(srvInterface.allocator,
                LibCSVParser<StringParsersImpl>);
    }
};

typedef LibCSVParserFactoryTmpl<StringParsers> LibCSVParserFactory;
RegisterFactory(LibCSVParserFactory);

typedef LibCSVParserFactoryTmpl<FormattedStringParsers> FormattedLibCSVParserFac
tory;
RegisterFactory(FormattedLibCSVParserFactory);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick and dirty way would be to just hardcode it.  It's using a callback to `handle_end_of_row`. Track the row number and just don't process the first row . Something like:

```
static void handle_end_of_row(int c, void *ptr) {
    // Ignore 'c' (the terminating character); trust that it's correct
    LibCSVParser *p = static_cast<LibCSVParser*>(ptr);
    p->colNum = 0;

    if (rowcnt <= 0) {
        p->bad_field = "";
        rowcnt++;
    } else if (p->bad_field.empty()) {
        p->writer->next();
    } else {
        // libcsv doesn't give us the whole row to reject.
        // So just write to the log.
        // TODO: Come up with something more clever.
        if (p->currSrvInterface) {
            p->currSrvInterface->log("Invalid CSV field value: '%s'  Row skipped.",
                                    p->bad_field.c_str());
        }
        p->bad_field = "";
    }
}
```

Also, best to initialize `rownum = 0` in `process` since I think it will call this for each file in your `COPY` statement.  There might be more clever ways of doing this.  Basically, this will just process the record and then discard it.

As for supporting `SKIP` generically... look at `TraditionalCSVParser` for how to handle parameter passing.  You'd have to add it to the parser factor `prepare` and send in the value to the `LibCSVParser` class and override `getParameterType`.  Then in `LibCSVParser` you need to accept the parameter in the constructor, and modify `process` to skip the first `skip` rows. Then use that value instead of the hardcoded `0` above.

Comment: One quick comment, I would be sure to test this using multiple files.  The docs aren't clear exactly how the input buffer works when multiple files are involved.  I would try 1 file, 2 files, then n+1 files where n = number of nodes. I would try this with and without `ON ANY NODE`.

Comment: @user645715 NP. Let me know how it works out for you. As I mentioned in my comment,  I'm not positive about how the input buffer works, but if it ends up not working the way I think it does, another idea might be to create a UDSource.